# LinkedIn rest api posts no content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, linkedin-api

I'm trying to post message via `/people/~/shares` POST.

The issue is that on some servers (I use local machine, testing, staging and production servers) message is posted but is completely blank.

The code is absolute identical on all servers, but on local machine and production server everything is ok and on testing/staging an issue appears.

**Xml to post:**

```
<share>
  <comment /> 
  <content>
    <title>My Title Here</title> 
    <submitted-url>http://www.mysite.com</submitted-url> 
  </content>
  <visibility>
    <code>anyone</code> 
  </visibility>
</share>
```

**Reponse status** : Created

I also thought that reason is in new linkedIn api features, but adding `rw_nus` scope to `requestToken` POST doesn't help

**UPDATE:** I've asked about this issue on linkedin forum and got a little hack/workaroud/note: text in `<comment>` block displays correctly, but there is nothing inside `<content>` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So issue was on the LinkedIn side and has been already [fixed](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/17545#comment-17545)